# how to display model data to html page

Tags: django, django-models

I am following this tutorials and created a model and can see the data from admin page.
https://djangoforbeginners.com/message-board/

However, i am unable to see the see the posts in the html page. My html pages is inside the template:

Model:

## pages/models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:50]
```

View:

## pages/views.py

```
class DiagramsPageView(TemplateView):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    template_name = 'diagrams.html'
    contex= {'posts': posts}
```

## pages/urls.py

```
from .views import DiagramsPageView, 

urlpatterns = [
    path('diagrams/', DiagramsPageView.as_view(), name='diagrams'),

  ]
```

The HTML template  page is here

```
<!-- templates/home.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
<h1>Diagrams</h1>
<h2>Styling Tables</h2>  

<ul>
 {{posts}}
</ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

The HTML page only outputting

```
Diagrams
Styling Tables
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables you declare `posts = Post.objects.all()` and `contex= {'posts': posts}` are not automatically passed to the context, you have to use `get_context_data`

```
class DiagramsPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'diagrams.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DiagramsPageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()
        return context
```

**Note**: *You have to iterate through the object*

And your html:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Diagrams</h1>
<h2>Styling Tables</h2>  

<ul>
  {% for post in posts %}
     {{ post }}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Or use ListView

```
class DiagramsPageView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'diagrams.html'
```

And your html:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Diagrams</h1>
<h2>Styling Tables</h2>  

<ul>
  {% for post in object_list %}
     {{ post }}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock content %}
```